# PH8 Cinterion module not detected as a modem driver issue

Tags: gsm, modem

I have been debugging a custom GSM board involving Cinterion ph8 module,and it finally was working ie; when i was searching for the device in the /dev/ it got detected as a ttyACM0 device.But it was not responding to the at&t commands.

I just don't know how to connect to internet because it was not detected as a proper modem,i don't know what could be the problem(Driver or hardware)

Or is there any other specific driver for this.

NOTE: i'm using UBUNTU 12.04 32-bit os and an i7processor,and i'm using a cinterion PH8 module for this.

Comment: It sounds like a driver problem.  Has the vendor got any newer driver version?

Comment: the problem was with the hardware we corrected it and is now working fine

Answer (score 0):

by factory PH8 came with an CDC_ACM drivers in the usd and serial in the RS232.

check that you kernel has the CDC_ACM driver.

Regards
ALopez